# ¿Por qué me aparece el error " Terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc' " en C++?

Tags: c++, array, linux, string, array-bidimensional

Estoy haciendo unas practicas de funciones con arrays por parámetros y al compilar a veces no me da ningún error, pero al ejecutar me lanza el error antes mencionado:

[image: Error al ejecutar]

Luego hay veces en las que si me da un error:

[image: Error al compilar]

Este es mi código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void prototipo(string a[][3]);

int main(){

  int x = 4;
  int y = 3;

  string prueba[4][3]={
      {"[   Materias  ]","[  Maestros  ]","[   Horario   ]"},
      {"[ Matematicas ]","[   Eduardo  ]","[10:00 - 11:00]"},
      {"[   Ciencias  ]","[   Gaston   ]","[11:00 - 12:00]"},
      {"[   Lenguaje  ]","[  Guadalupe ]","[12:00 - 13:00]"}
  };


  prototipo(prueba[4][3]);

  return 0;
  }

  void prototipo(string a[4][3]){
    int fila;
    int columna;

    for(fila = 0; fila < 4; fila++){
    for(columna = 0; columna < 3; columna++){
          cout<<a[fila][columna];
      }
          cout<<endl;
    }

  }
```

Comment: Por favor, no utilices imágenes de forma innecesaria. El código, errores, etc, se deben colocar **como texto**. Un saludo.

Comment: Ok gracias por el consejo, yo no lo consideraba como innecesario.

Comment: ¿Sabes cómo resolverlo? El error

Comment: Yo **no veo** ningún error. Tengo problemas de visión, y solo aprecio 2 manchas negras. Mi software de dictado no sabe interpretar imágenes aun.

Comment: Bueno no te preocupes, ya logré resolverlo, inventaré un programa para que te lo pueda leer ;)

Comment: Se agradece la buena voluntad ... pero creo que sería **bastante más rápido** el que intentaras limitar el uso de imágenes :-)

Comment: Yo tengo 40 años, vista cansada y miopía. Me cuesta mucho ver el contenido de esas imágenes... te garantizo que es mucho más rápido y tiene mucha mejor acogida copiapegar el texto.

Comment: Si, ya no usaré más imágenes

Comment: Pero igualmente me gustaría hacer un programa que les ayude con eso, perdonen mi ignorancia es la primera vez que uso stack overflow, tengo 17 años soy muy novato.

Comment: Igualmente tomo estos comentarios como retroalimentación para aprender

Answer (score 1):

El error está en que está en que al ejecutar la función el parámetro no debe llevar corchetes ya que es una referencia:

```
 prototipo(prueba[4][3]); // Esto es erroneo
 prototipo(prueba); //Esto es lo correcto
```

Aparte de eso el parámetro siempre debe saber cuál es el valor de la dimensión y de la matriz por lo que debemos declarar una constante por lo que el código queda asi:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>



using namespace std;

  #define x 4
  #define y 3

  void draw(string [][y]);

  int main(){

      string prueba[x][y]={
          {"[   Materias  ]","[  Maestros  ]","[   Horario   ]"},
          {"[ Matematicas ]","[   Eduardo  ]","[10:00 - 11:00]"},
          {"[   Ciencias  ]","[   Gaston   ]","[11:00 - 12:00]"},
          {"[   Lenguaje  ]","[  Guadalupe ]","[12:00 - 13:00]"}
      };


      draw(prueba);

      return 0;
  }

  void draw(string a[4][3]){

      int fila;
      int columna;

      for(fila = 0; fila < 4; fila++){
          for(columna = 0; columna < 3; columna++){
              cout<<a[fila][columna];
          }
          cout<<endl;
      }

  }
```